# How to solve the following recurrence using the substitution method?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I need to prove a tight bound on the following recurrence using the Substitution method:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n/log(n)
```

I have arrived to the "guess" part of the Substitution method and know that `T(n)` is `O(n*log(log(n)))` by using recursion tree and iteration method. But I have trouble figuring out  how to proceed from the inductive step both for big-O and Omega:

```
Assume  T(n/2) <= c*(n/2)log(log(n/2))
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n/log(n) <= 2c*(n/2)log(log(n/2)) + n/log(n)

Assume  T(n/2) => c*(n/2)log(log(n/2))
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n/log(n) => 2c*(n/2)log(log(n/2)) + n/log(n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume

```
T(n/2) <= (n/2) log log (n/2) = (n/2) log (log n - 1).
```

Then

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n/log n
     <= n log (log n - 1) + n/log n
     = n log log n - n (log log n - log (log n - 1) + 1/log n),
```

so it suffices to show that `log log n - log (log n - 1) >= 1/log n`, which is an instance of the general inequality `log k - log (k - 1) >= 1/k`, proved by integrating `1/x` from `x = k - 1` to `x = k` and applying the mean value theorem. (Visually, a rectangle of width `1` and height `1/k` fits under the curve of `1/x` from `x = k - 1` to `x = k`.)

The lower bound is similar; use the inequality `log k - log (k - 1) <= 1/(k - 1) <= 2/k` for `k >= 2`.